# My Rep doesn't add: 30,000 + 20 = 30,021

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

Yesterday, I hit 30,000 rep.
I took a screenshot of it, so I know it was exact.

In the last day, I got two upvotes, for a +20.
But now my rep is 30,021.

I don't see anything else to explain it in my [Reputation Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34824/abelenky?tab=reputation).
So where did my extra point come from?

Comment: Are you showing removed posts?  I'm showing a question was removed yesterday with one of your answers on it.

Comment: @bluefeet:  That is it.  (I'd never even noticed the Removed Posts check before...) It shows the missing +1.  Thx.

Comment: You start accruing interest on your rep once you're over 25k.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What probably happened is that you downvoted somebody and then either that question was deleted or you un-downvoted it.

In my experience, you get reputation notifications when this happens, but I'm not finding anything in my reputation log indicating that I un-downvoted something, so It probably doesn't appear there, or at least not by default.

Comment: You need to have ticked the "show deleted posts" checkbox for these to appear in your history, but yes, there's usually a(n annoying) notification regardless.